# Discretizing Exponential distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, exponential-distribution

I am working on a packet generator that can generate packets of 50 different sizes and the packet sizes follow exponential distribution. Given a mean packet size how can I choose the 50 packet sizes from the continuous exponential distribution so that the resulting discrete distribution accurately follows the continuous one.Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you define what 'accuracy' you'd like to optimize?

Comment: Hi Glen..Thanks for the reply.I am not familiar with the probability concepts so please excuse me if I am wrong.The paper that I work on says the packet sizes follow exponential distribution and the 50 packet sizes are between 64 and 1536.Does that mean the moments of the two distributions need to be equal?

Comment: This is how the packet generator works. There is a 25bit linear feedback shift register that generates numbers from the uniform distribution and on each clock(duration 6.4ns) this number is compared to boundary vectors that partition numbers from 0 to 2^25 into segments whose sizes  are proportional to the probability of the packet sizes.If the generated random number is less than or equal to a particular boundary vector then the packet size whose probability matches to the boundary vector is chosen for packet generation.

Comment: Matching moments is one approach, but that's not what I'd have called 'accuracy'. What do you need for it to achieve? Failing that, what are the consequences of however much *inaccuracy* you end up with? (this might gives us some clues about your loss function, which would lead to something to optimize)

Answer (score 1):

See Proposition B here:
http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~jkennan/research/DiscreteApprox.pdf

It shows that the best $n$-point discrete approximation, where "best" is defined relative to an $L^p$ metric (for any $p > 0$), is one that places equal density on each point.

So if $F$ is the exponential CDF you should choose your fifty support points $x_i^*$ such that $F(x_i^*) = \frac{2i-1}{2n}$ for $1 \le i \le 50$.  To do that you'll need a way to calculate the inverse exponential CDF, for example in Matlab you would use expinv().

Then assign each point equal mass, which will be $1/50$.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is poorly specified as it's given, so forget the 50 packet size case - give us an example for how you'd do it with only 3 different packet sizes. That'll clarify your problem so we can make reasonable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The discrete analog of the exponential distribution is the geometric distribution on $\{0, 1, \dotsc\}$.  For a given mean $\mu$, let $p = \frac{\mu}{\mu + 1}$.